# Importing & initializing GCP googleapis/google-cloud-python clients

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-python

As far as I understand, the suggested way to interact with GCP using python is to use the [google-cloud-python](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python) client.

So far I have not been able to initialize or even import such a client in my project and was not able to find any documentation about it.

Can anyone help me figure out the import and init statements for the [Resource Client](https://github.com/googleapis/python-resource-manager) as well as the [Compute Engine Client](https://github.com/googleapis/python-compute)?

From there on I assume I'll figure out the rest using the docs.

Comment: What is it that you're trying to do? Asking because I'm not sure what RC and CEC have to do with the cloud-python client, why you want to combine these, etc. Makes it kinda hard to answer, atm.

Answer (score 3):

So I figured it out, primarily I had an issue with another google package that messed up my dependencies.

The import statement is as follows:

```
from google.cloud.resourcemanager_v3.services.projects.client import ProjectsClient
```

and the initialization is simply this:

```
client = ProjectsClient()
```

Note however, that this relies on an existing application default credentials file existing on the machine, which can be created by running the following command in the console:

```
gcloud auth application-default login
```